# UITableView not following constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have in the bottom of the screen a view containing 4 image views that I use as navigation buttons. That view is pinned to bottom layer by "0". Now my tableview is above this view and I have made a constraint of "10" from tableview to my "navigation view." I have two problems. When my tableview contains more rows than the screen can hold it puts the cells  "behind" my "navigation view" even though I made the constraint it shouldn't. Now when I flip the screen to landscape mode it actually makes my navigation view disappear from the screen. I don't understand why as I pinned the bottom view to bottom layer. (2 questions)
Then of course my 2nd row decides to use much bigger font when I load in more rows, which is something I don't even want to bother you guys with yet, I think my simulator is playing tricks with me..

Anyway, I appreciate any help on my 2 problems above. Thank you

EDIT: Here I took some pictures: 
http://i.imgur.com/LA9Spt0.png (this shows what i mean with the tableview pushing away the lower view even though the lower view is constrained to the bottom layer and the tableview has a constrain leading to the lower view (menu bar))

http://i.imgur.com/b6VoqFk.png Here what happens when I "pull" the tableview downwards to see  more cells it blocks the upper label and top bar (which contains the logo I had to remove for reasons with the company) I tried to use :setBounces and setAlwaysVertBounces set to NO but then I can't scroll down the tableview when more cells exist.

(addition to img. nr 2)multiple cells makes the cells hide behind the lower menu navigation bar. I did make a constrain between the tableview and lower menu bar, shouldn't I be able to make the tableview "create" a scroll bar so u can scroll down instead of cells hiding behind the menu bar.

Thanks, any help much appreciated!

Comment: You need to provide either a screenshot from storyboard with your layout or link to your project, so people can take a look and help you. What you're describing is pretty obvious auto-layout configuration and should work without any issues.

Comment: Also do you create `UITableView` inside `UITableViewController` in storyboard?

Comment: Yes obv it is auto layout config. I will try and upload a picture, but I don't see how its gonna describe the constraints that I described. I just created the UITableView inside my "view controller", mainly because the table view controller couldn't be put inside that controller (then Id have to create a new "page/view controller" not being part of the rest of my front page.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have some conflicts, or missing constraints.

You can see if you have constraints errors in the nib, in the 'view hierarchy' column in the left side of your nib, you will see a little red arrow..

Or that you have some conflict which you can see at the console when running you app.

Thanks

Comment: It says my views are "misplaced". My metrics are set to inferred, I don't know if this has anything to do with the misplacement (btw all elements are in the right place when I run the app on phone, its only if the tableview holds more cells than able to display on screen that it starts messing around). The book I've been reading (iOS 7 dev. exploring the sdk pt 2) is maybe too old to have the metrics size inferred thing, I did wonder what it makes good for to have a screen in IB being like this (inferred).